# Special characters are not read by the Screen Reader

Tags: wai-aria, screen-readers, section508, nvda

The following contents of the HTML file are not read by the screen reader. The NVDA reads the text until "read by the Screen Reader" then it only reads & (and) = (equal) < (less) > (greater) and not any other special characters.

```html
<p>
 I want these characters to be read by the Screen Reader "&=`"<>\[]-". 
</p>
```

Comment: Well for most normal situations, it probably doesn’t make much sense to read them. I’d try wrapping them into an individual element each and put a `title` attribute with the text you want to be read on it, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique intended for emoji: http://tink.uk/accessible-emoji/

> These things are simple to fix though. We need to tell the browser to expose the emoji (or its container) as an image, then give it an accessible name.
>
> Use the ARIA `img` role to expose the  as an image in the accessibility tree:
>
> `<span role="img">&#9731;</span>`
>
> Then use the aria-label attribute to give the emoji an accessible name:
>
> `<span role="img" aria-label="Snowman">&#9731;</span>`
>
> […]
>
> Now the browser will expose the emoji as an image in the accessibility tree, and use the value of the aria-label attribute as its accessible name. When a screen reader queries the accessibility tree it will use this information to tell the user that there is an image of a snowman (☃) on the page.

You have to give it a role otherwise the `aria-label` will not be announced.

Comment: Oh no, don't do it for plain ASCII characters! Just set appropriate punctuation level in your screen reader.

Comment: Oh, right, good point. For some reason in my head I was thinking extended ASCII. Getting end users to change their configuration just to get information on this site seems unlikely, however, so OP might still need to address this in a similar way.

Comment: To re-state, asking your users to change their SR settings just to use your site is likely a non-starter. I am pressing this point because I see I was down-voted for this answer but I suspect for the wrong reason based on the first comment.

Comment: Definitely. If you absolutely need these chars to be read, you might do something like `<span aria-label="all the chars delimited by a space, like: ( ) ` ! @ . . .">yourString</span>`. I think, this will do.

Comment: See my answer above (last line). A screen reader will not announce `aria-label` on a `<span>`. Hence the need for a `role`.